# override variables SASS variables without generating new theme in extjs 5

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Is it possible to override SASS variables and place the .scss files under  /sass/src folder and build the project ?

I do not want to create a new theme and override, since i only have minor change.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

For variables, you need to create a directory structure in sass/var/ that reflects your JS class structure. For example, if you have this class:

```
// In app/view/main/Main.js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {});
```

The you would have this SCSS:

```
// In sass/var/view/main/Main.scss
$base-color: #333;
```

You can read more about this here:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/theming.html#Changing_Theme_Variables_in_Your_Application

Comment: I have to override Extjs tab panel. 
so i have created /sass/src/tab/Panel.scss at the root level (sass folder already generated by sencha ).
but i dont see the config being picked from the scss files.

Comment: sorry, correction: i added it under
/sass/src/Ext/tab/Panel.scss